# Как получить состояние другого модуля в Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Всем привет. Не могу понять как в одном модуле Vuex получить состояние другого модуля, используя namespace.

moduleWS.js

```
  export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
      statusConnectToWS: false
    }
  }
```

moduleRest.js

```
  export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
      restServer: 'linux'
    }
  }
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import moduleRest from './modules/moduleRest'
import moduleWS from './modules/moduleWS'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleRest,
    moduleWS
  }
})
```

Прошу показать пример как в  модуле moduleWS через геттер и состояние получить restServer. Если такое возможно. Через документацию не доходит.

Варианты с использованием гетера из модуля moduleRest или описать это в  компоненте не устраивает по соображениям перфекционизма.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    statusConnectToWS: false,
  },
  getters: {
    getRestServer1: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {
      let a = rootGetters['moduleRest/someGetter']
      return a
    },
    getRestServer2: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {
      let b = rootState.moduleRest.restServer
      return b
    }
  },
```